# Synapse SQL: Merging staging table into primary table and auto-increment identity

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

Azure Synapse has a different approach to primary keys (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-table-constraints) which does not allow traditional identity columns (e.g., `INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`)

I would like to use merge statements to update a table that I have, but using Synapse SQL, I am unsure how to get auto-increasing primary keys when I merge in new data. Consider the following MWE:

```
CREATE TABLE [table1]
  (  
    [primaryKey] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id] INT,
    [name] VARCHAR(25)
  )  
WITH ( CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
DISTRIBUTION = HASH([id])
);

CREATE TABLE [table1_staging]
  (  
    [id] INT,
    [name] VARCHAR(25)
  );

INSERT INTO [table1_staging] 
(id, name) VALUES (1, 'john');


-- run merge
MERGE [table1] AS TARGET
USING [table1_staging] AS SOURCE 
-- match on ID
ON (TARGET.id = SOURCE.id)
-- when no match; insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT ([id], [name]) VALUES(SOURCE.[id], SOURCE.[name]);

-- cannot update identity column
```

The recommended way to create a primary key (`INT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED NOT ENFORCED`) does not auto-increment, leading to merge failures as it is not allowing NULL.

Comment: "cannot update identity column"? Your statement never updates an identity column, and also I've never come across a case where you wated to. You'll need to explain in more detail.

Comment: Can you post the error that you get? I don't want to pay for a Synapse instance to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to turn it on.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON;

Answer (score 0):

From MSFT, it is not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true#remarks

`During the preview, MERGE…WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT is not supported for tables with IDENTITY columns.`